# UAC shows unknown publisher first few times for signed file

Tags: code-signing, uac

I've digitally signed my exe with a StartCom code signing cert.

However, when I download it, the first couple of times I try to run the exe on a clean Win7 box, I see an "unknown" publisher. After a while, when I try to run the same exe, I see my publisher details correctly.

Any idea what's going on here and how to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe the root certificates has not been updated, or you dont have an internet connection.

Comment: I definitely have an internet connection - I just downloaded the file from my web server. How would I know if the root cert is updated or not (or force an update)?

Comment: I know there is an update after Windows 7 SP1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125

Comment: Haven't seen this issue in a while, so I'm assuming it was fixed by the update mentioned above.